# What is the difference between pandas str.extractall() and pandas str.extract()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, extract

I am trying to find all matched words from a column of strings and a giving word list. If I use pandas `str.extract()`, I can get the first matched word, since I needs all the matched words, so I think pandas `str.extractall()` will work, however, I only got a `ValueError`.

What is the problem here?

```
 df['findWord'] = df['text'].str.extractall(f"({'|'.join(wordlist)})").fillna('')
```

```
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long long'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas.Series.str.extract) returns the first match. [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html#pandas.Series.str.extractall) generates one row per match.

Example, let's match A and the following letter.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['ABC', 'ADAE']})
#     col
# 0   ABC
# 1  ADAE

df['col'].str.extractall('(A.)')
```

This created a novel index level named  "match" that identifies the match number. Matches from the same row are identified by the same first index level.

Output:

```
          0
  match    
0 0      AB
1 0      AD
  1      AE
```

With `extract`:

```
df['col'].str.extract('(A.)')
```

Output:

```
    0
0  AB
1  AD
```

###### aggregating the output of `extractall`

```
(df['col']
 .str.extractall('(A.)')
 .groupby(level='match').agg(','.join)
)
```

Output:

```
           0
match       
0      AB,AD
1         AE
```

Comment: thank you so much for answering my question, how can i get 'AD' and 'AE' as one value?

Comment: You can `groupby(level='match').agg(...)` with the aggregation function depending on which output you want. I added an example in the answer.